# Google sheet : my downloaded sheet in .ods (calc) doesn't recover formulas with REGEXMATC

Tags: google-sheets, libreoffice-calc

I my Google sheet I have cell with formulas like this

```
=IF(REGEXMATCH(K12;"Oui");IF(AND(REGEXMATCH($C12;"Oui"); REGEXMATCH(K12;"Oui"));L$7;L$8);0)
```

This formala becomes

```
=SIERREUR(__xludf.dummyfunction("IF(REGEXMATCH(K12,""Oui""),IF(AND(REGEXMATCH($C12,""Oui""), REGEXMATCH(K12,""Oui"")),L$7,L$8),0)");11)
```

in Libreoffice Calc.

What is wrong ? Is there a mean to fix this problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your expressions do not contain any [regular expression](http://www.regular-expressions.info/quickstart.html) special characters, so you can also use the `find()` function that exists in both Google Sheets and LibreOffice.

Modify your formula like this:

```
=if(not(iserror(find("Oui"; K12))); if(not(iserror(find("Oui"; $C12))); L$7; L$8); 0)
```

If you need actual regular expressions, you will have to edit the formula after each move from Google Sheets to LibreOffice.

LibreOffice does not have a `regexmatch()` function, but it has a `REGEX()` function that can be used to imitate the former. For example:

```
=NOT(ISERROR(REGEX("Non Oui Si"; "Oui")))
```

...will give `TRUE`, while:

```
=NOT(ISERROR(REGEX("Dweezil"; "Oui")))
```

...will give `FALSE`.

These LibreOffice expressions accomplish the same as `regexmatch()` in Google Sheets, save for certain differences in regex patterns.

See:

- Google Sheets [regexmatch()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098292)
- Google Sheets [find()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094126)
- LibreOffice [REGEX()](https://help.libreoffice.org/6.2/en-US/text/scalc/01/func_regex.html)
- LibreOffice [FIND()](https://help.libreoffice.org/7.1/en-US/text/scalc/01/04060110.html)

Comment: Thank you very much. I used your suggested replacement formula and it works fine now. BTW, will it be also good when downloading for Excel?

Comment: It should work. Test it to find out. These three products are not the same and do not have identical feature sets.